# Botium - Login credentials for Botium

Tags: botium-box

How can I get the Login credentials for the Botium Box community Edition? I tried with the user name as a tester and password as no one knows. In this credentials, I'm unable to create a bot and to run the chatbot, since I don't have 'Register New Chatbot' button in chatbots window.
[Added picture, where there is no button for registering the new chat bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETm2w.png)

Answer (score 0):

When doing an on-premise-installation of Botium Box, there are several users created by default, matching a common user hierarchy pattern:

- admin
- testmanager
- tester
- guest

For all of them, the default password is *nooneknows*.

You are referring to the online trial - management access is locked there.